# Running PowerShell terminal in 2.0 mode

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.16.1
- OS Version: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Is it possible to run the PowerShell terminal using PowerShell v2.0?  I have an older SharePoint farm that requires earlier version of PowerShell and would like to run that version instead of more current versions.  When I open VS Code on my server the PowerShell terminal crashes.

Here is the log of the crash.

```
9/18/2017 10:09:24 AM [NORMAL] - Visual Studio Code v1.16.1 64-bit
9/18/2017 10:09:24 AM [NORMAL] - PowerShell Extension v1.4.3
9/18/2017 10:09:24 AM [NORMAL] - Operating System: Windows 64-bit
9/18/2017 10:09:24 AM [NORMAL] - Language server starting --
9/18/2017 10:09:24 AM [NORMAL] -     exe: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
9/18/2017 10:09:24 AM [NORMAL] -     args: C:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.3\scripts\Start-EditorServices.ps1 -EditorServicesVersion '1.4.1' -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '1.4.3' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'C:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.3\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'C:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.3\logs\1505754564-f1d3cfae-50af-4f74-9503-061208469b8d1505754561535\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'C:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.3\sessions\PSES-VSCode-10764-479503' -FeatureFlags @()
9/18/2017 10:09:25 AM [NORMAL] - powershell.exe started, pid: 6412
9/18/2017 10:09:25 AM [NORMAL] - powershell.exe terminated or terminal UI was closed
9/18/2017 10:10:25 AM [NORMAL] - Language server startup failed.
9/18/2017 10:10:25 AM [ERROR] - The language service could not be started: 
9/18/2017 10:10:25 AM [ERROR] - Timed out waiting for session file to appear.
```

Comment: Can't you just specify a different powershell executable in `settings.json`?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same symptoms after updating VS Code (1.25.1) and PowerShell extension (1.8.2). Discovered that C:\Users\USERNAME.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.8.2\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\Start-EditorServices.ps1 was failing to launch by looking at the logs and trying to launch it manually from a separate PowerShell instance with the same arguments. It returned the following prompt: **Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher? [V] Never run [D] Do not run [R] Run once [A] Always run [?] Help (default is "D"):** indicating that the digital signature was not trusted.

To remedy this I performed the following:

1. Browse to the file noted in the error message above. (ex. C:\Users\USERNAME.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.8.2\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\Start-EditorServices.ps1)
2. Right click on the file and choose Properties | Digital Signatures
3. Select the signature and click Details | View Certificate
4. Choose the Details tab and click Copy to File...
5. Save the file with a .CER extension.
6. Using the Certificates MMC Snapin, import this file into the Trusted Publishers Certificate Store on the Local Machine.

(original solution post in https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1360 )